# How do I add a class to a default bootstrap class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class

Im want to give the panel-heading class an identifier so i can target it in my css without changing any of the other panel-heading's, how do i go about this?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="login">Welcome Back!</h2>
    </div>`
```

Comment: If you plan on using it multiple times you could squeeze another class in after panel-heading, like <div class="panel-heading custom-class">

Comment: How would I write that in my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second class by simply adding it in the `class` attribute, the classes will have to be separated by a space.

In your case, it will be:

```
<div class="panel panel-default custom_class"> <!-- Note the new class -->
    <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="login">Welcome Back!</h2>
</div>
```

In your CSS you can then do:

```
.custom_class {
    /* Your styles */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Add another class to the particular `panel-heading` you're referring to:

   ```
   <div class="panel-heading classname">
   ```

And then target it via CSS with `.panel-heading.classname { }`

2. Use a child selector to target only the panel-heading you need:

   ```
   .panel:first-child > .panel-heading { }
   .panel:last-child > .panel-heading { }
   .panel:nth-child(2) > .panel-heading { }
   ```

As you can see from point 2 above, I'm using a child selector on the parent `.panel` class and then selecting the `.panel-heading` of that parent only.

Please note the (2) in the nth-child selector above can be changed to select whatever you need (in the example I've given it would obviously target the second one).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your class, Bootstrap is just a set of ready css class to be used and can be used with other classes as well as can be overrided

```html
<div id="my_css_id" class="panel panel-default my_css_class_1">
    <div class="panel-heading my_css_class_1">
      <h2 class="login">Welcome Back!</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default Add-custome-class">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h2 class="login">Welcome Back!</h2>
    </div>
</div>`
```

**CSS**

```
.Add-custome-class
{
// CSS Properties 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. Thanks